# how can i get tfs 2013 (web) history burn down chart export to somewhere maybe excel?

Tags: reporting-services, history, tfs-web-access, burndowncharts

[image: the burn down chart on tfs 2013 through web access]

My boss found there was no way to view a history burn data chart on tfs 2013 through web access, only current data can be seen like the picture shown. So he wonders how to export history burn down chart, maybe last month chart or something.

I searched ways to export burn down chart, and found maybe i could use SQL Server Reporting Services. Later we found this from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433251.aspx)[image]

I wonder what is to generate a history burn down chart in excel or somewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Reporting Services installed for TFS then you can schedule the Burndown and Burn Rate report.
See [details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380678.aspx)

Comment: hi, so you mean by using this we can retrieve last month's burn chart for instance, today? Or you mean schedule that every month, i can scan last month's burn chart which was exported last month?